# Express routes not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have just started a brand new Express app following the [Code Magazine's tutorial](http://www.codemag.com/article/1210041).

Here's my app and the `/img` route definitions.
[image: Routes]

When I browse to `http://localhost:3000/img` or `http://localhost:3000/img/`, I gets a `404 Not Found` response.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting your `/img` route on `/img`. That is to say, you would need to `GET /img/img` to hit your route. Replace `/img` with `/` in your `img.js` file.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not allow me to accept an answer under 10 mins.

Comment: Sorry, me being impatient! Thanks.